# How do I change the attributes of elements in a list of instances of a user defined class?

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through a list, *workerl* of instances of a class I defined, *worker*, and based on one of the class attributes, *isemployed*, grab 5 of those and call a function on them, *fire()*.  I've tried many different ways, but I either get stuck in an endless loop or I get the wrong values.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, the code is below, and the part I need help with is commented in bold, but other tips are appreciated as well. Thanks!

```
from random import choice
import sys

class Population:
    """total population of workers"""
    workerl = []
    workers = 0
    g_rate = 1
    y = 0
    ui = 0
    c = 5

    def __init__(self, ui, workers):
        # probability of a worker becoming unemployed
        # low in booms, high in recessions, could be a proxy for i
        self.ui = ui
        self.workers = workers
        self.workerl = []
        for i in range(workers):
            x = Worker()
            self.workerl.append(x)
        for i in range(workers / 10.):
            self.workerl[i].fire()

    def countEmployed(self):
        """displays number of employed workers in a population"""
        employed = 0
        for worker in self.workerl:
            if worker.isemployed == True:
                employed = employed + 1
        return employed

    def countUnemployed(self):
        """displays number of unemployed workers in a population"""
        unemployed = 0
        for worker in self.workerl:
            if worker.isemployed == False:
                unemployed = unemployed + 1
        return unemployed   

    def employedl(self):
        employedl = []
        for worker in self.workerl:
            if worker.isemployed:
                employedl.append(worker)
        return employedl

    def unemployedl(self):
        unemployedl = []
        for worker in self.workerl:
            if worker.isemployed == False:
                unemployedl.append(worker)
        return unemployedl

    def lookingl(self):
        lookingl = []
        for worker in self.workerl:
            if worker.islooking:
                lookingl.append(worker)
        return employedl


    def advance(self, time):
        """advances the population units of time"""

        # updates assets
        for worker in self.workerl:
            if worker.isemployed == True:
                worker.assets = worker.assets + worker.salary
            else:
                worker.assets = worker.assets + self.ui - self.c        

        #calculates current y
        tmp_y = 0
        for worker in self.workerl:
            tmp_y = worker.assets + tmp_y
        self.y = tmp_y

        # fires some workers, random turnover
        # THIS IS THE PART I NEED HELP WITH
        # as discussed above, i need to pick 5 workers from workerl
        # where isemployed == True
        # and then call their fire() method


        # makes job search decisions for unemployed
        jobs = self.y / 10
        jobseekers = 0
        for worker in self.workerl:
            if worker.islooking:
                jobseekers =+ 1

        if jobs/jobseekers > 1:
            d = 1
        elif jobs/jobseekers < 0:
            d = 0
        else:
            d = jobs / jobseekers

        for worker in self.workerl:
            if worker.isemployed == False:
                if ((d * 5 + (1 - d) * (self.ui - self.c)) > self.ui):
                    worker.look()
                else:
                    worker.unlook()

        # hires some workers
        jobcount = jobs
        if d == 1:
            for worker in self.workerl:
                if worker.islooking:
                    worker.hire()
        elif d == 0:
            pass
        else:
            for i in range(jobs):
                if self.workerl[i].islooking:
                    self.workerl[i].hire()


        #calculates growth rate, updates y
        tmp2_y = 0
        for worker in self.workerl:
            tmp2_y = worker.assets + tmp2_y
        self.g_rate = (tmp_y / self.y) + 1.
        self.y = tmp_y


# population as an array of workers     
class Worker:
    """a worker in a population"""
    isemployed = True
    islooking = False
    assets = 0

    salary = choice(range(10))

    def fire(self):
        self.isemployed = False
        self.islooking = True

    def hire(self):
        self.isemployed = True
        self.islooking = False

    def look(self):
        self.islooking = True

    def unlook(self):
        self.islooking = False


def main():

    x = Population(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))  
    x.advance(1)
    print x.countEmployed()
    print x.countUnemployed()
    print x.y

main()
```

Comment: I hope I don't sound too rude when I say "TL;DR". Please prepare a smaller code sample that exhibits the behavior that concerns you.

Comment: As written this wouldn't even compile from the syntax errors.

Comment: @Ignacio I think the whole class definition is relevant, both of Worker and of Population, but if it's too much, the blurb at the top describes what I need help with.

Comment: @Daenyth yeah, I just fixed up some small things, it compiles now, but that's not my problem.  Other ideas?

Comment: The classes are still not indented properly. Can you post the fixed code so people would see what trouble you're having?

Comment: And range() is given a float() argument, which obviously won't do...

Comment: @Boaz, okay, the fixed code is posted.  range() throws a warning, but doesn't seem to be giving me any problems.  what i specifically need help with is how to accomplish the task in the caps lock halfway down.

Comment: 1.  Python is never 'compiled'  Errors appear as they are encountered by the interpreter  2.  TL;DR is a cheap way of saying "I'm too lazy to help, but I want to make you look like the lazy one"

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the random.choice function.  It allows you to choose a randomly selected value from a list.  Here's how it might work:

```
class Population:
    employee_list = []
    ...

    # Create a set that will contain the unique indices  of newly fired employees
    fired_indices = set()

    # Keep count of how many we have fired      
    fired_count = 0
    while fired_count < 5:
        # Because we are using index numbers for bookkeeping, we need to chose from
        # the list of indexes not the list of employees
        # The xrange is much more efficient if we have large lists
        i = random.choice( xrange( len( employee_list ) ) )

        # Selection criteria -> employed and not already fired in *this* round
        if employee_list[i].employed and i not in fired_indices:
            employee_list[i].employed = false
            fired_indices.add( i )
            fired_count += 1
```

The problem with this approach is that it is possible to choose the same worker many times (which I think you don't want to do) and have to keep rejecting him as a valid choice.  You might also select a lot of workers that are already unemployed before you find one that isn't.  These sort of redundancies add extra iterations to the selection loop, and you lose efficiency.

This could work more efficiently if you had two separate lists in your Population class.  You could have 1 list for employed workers and 1 for unemployed.  If you kept two separate lists, selection would be very easy.  You could avoid selecting workers that were already unemployed, and you could use random.sample to choose k unique selections from the list.  Here is an example:

```
class Population:
    employed_list = []
    unemployed_list = []
    ...

    fired_indices = random.sample( xrange( len( employed_list ) ) ) 
    for i in fired_indices:
        fired_employee = employed_list.pop( i )
        unemployed_list.append( fired_employee )
    ...
```

Of course, if you are a fan of list comprehensions, you could do it all in one line:

```
 unemployed_list.extend( [ employed_list.pop( i ) for i in random.sample( xrange( len( employed_list ) ) ] )
```

Hope this helps.  It's always a good idea to use the dir() method on modules to see if they have useful stuff you might be looking for:

```
>>> dir( random )
['BPF', 'LOG4', 'NV_MAGICCONST', 'RECIP_BPF', 'Random', 'SG_MAGICCONST', 'SystemRandom', 'TWOPI', 'WichmannHill', '_BuiltinMethodType', '_MethodType', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '_acos', '_cos', '_e', '_exp', '_hexlify', '_inst', '_log', '_pi', '_random', '_sin', '_sqrt', '_test', '_test_generator', '_urandom', '_warn', 'betavariate', '**choice**', 'expovariate', 'gammavariate', 'gauss', 'getrandbits', 'getstate', 'jumpahead', 'lognormvariate', 'normalvariate', 'paretovariate', 'randint', 'random', 'randrange', '**sample**', 'seed', 'setstate', 'shuffle', 'uniform', 'vonmisesvariate', 'weibullvariate']
```

Answer (score 0):

You pick a random sample like this:

```
import random

for worker in random.sample(self.employedl(), k=5): # pick 5
    worker.fire()
```

Btw, you can really cut down your code with list comprehensions, ie:

```
def employedl(self):
    return [worker for worker in self.workerl if worker.isemployed]
```

Comment: This isn't very efficient.  You are creating a new list that is a reduction of the first.  If the employee list is large, a lot of extra and unnecessary work is being done.

Comment: @dusktreader: I don't want to speculate about the size of the list, nor do I want to rewrite his entire code, so I just answered the question. So yeah, there are plenty optimizations left in case they are ever needed.